# Alias subnetworks with Google Cloud IPSec VPN

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, site-to-site-vpn, vpn-client, google-cloud-vpn

My company's infrastructure is hosted on Google Cloud. We'd like to connect a network of one our clients with site-to-site (IPSec) VPN. I've setup one on Google Cloud but we have a problem. Our subnetwork (10.10.0.0/16) is overlapping with their subnetworks (10.10.0.0/24). We have to solve this on our end, so on Google Cloud. Any idea how we can achieve this?

I tried to add a new subnet 192.168.64.0/24 to our VMs, The tunnel comes comes up.

But connectivity still fails. Traffic inbound and outbound failing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlapping subnetworks with Google Cloud IPSec VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/989268/overlapping-subnetworks-with-google-cloud-ipsec-vpn)

Comment: Jofre . No that does not help